# HTML and JavaScript make search input ready for URL

Tags: javascript, html, url, search-engine, google-search

I am making a webpage so I can search google from a custom page.
But when I click search it does search my input on google but the URL should be different when I input # and % and all these characters.
So my question is how do I convert something like this :

```
http://www.google.com/#q=Hello World C#
```

to this :

```
http://www.google.com/#q=HEllo+world+C%23
```

using JavaScript

EDIT :
This is the function I tried to use

```
    $('button#SubmitSearch').click
    (
        function()
        {
            window.location = encodeURIComponent("https://www.google.nl/#q=" + $('input#SearchBar').val());
        }
    );
```

and

```
    $('button#SubmitSearch').click
    (
        function()
        {
            window.location = "https://www.google.nl/#q=" + $('input#SearchBar').val();
        }
    );
```

Comment: You'll need to encode the search text. There's a handy Javascript function that does this, take a look at `encodeURIComponent`

Answer (score 1):

Using [encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI), eg :

```
console.log(encodeURI('http://www.google.com/#q=Hello World C#'));
> "http://www.google.com/#q=Hello%20World%20C#"
```

Or 
[encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

```
console.log(encodeURIComponent('Hello World C#'));
> "Hello%20World%20C%23"
```

From your OP :

```
$('button#SubmitSearch').click(function(){
    window.location = "https://www.google.nl/#q=" + encodeURIComponent($('input#SearchBar').val());
});
```

Comment: I wouldn't even have mentioned your *or* solution as it's kind of inferior in this context given that you would need to append the base URL.

Answer (score 0):

use the function encodeURIComponent:

```
encodeURIComponent('this is a string with special characters like # and ?')
```

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

try this
Var search = document.getElementById("searchbox");
Then use addeventlistener or onClick

key=key.replace(/ /g,"+"); 
   document.location("http://google.com/#q" + search.value);